# Dynamic link from php string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been racking my brain on how to do this with javascript. What I'm attempting is to have a link change depending on what selection is made from the drop down menu. I have been unsuccessful trying to find an article on here that fits my needs.
Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="storefrm">
<?php
require ("dbconnect.php");
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<div class="label">Select Store:</div>

<select name="stores" id="stores">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `storeconst` ORDER BY `Store` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
echo "<option value='".$d['GenManageEmail']."'>".$d['Store']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</form>  
<script>
$('#sendto').click(function(){
$('#storefrm').attr('action', 'mailto:'+$('#stores').val());
$('#storefrm').submit();
});
</script>
<button name="send" id="sendto" type="button">Send</button>
```

I'm a php newbie and javascript newbie. How do I have a link or button change when a store is selected. 
Thanks

Comment: do you want to make cascading dropdown  ? please clear

Comment: The drop down is generated from my mySQL database. I would like a button or a link to change depending on what store is selected. Here is my table: http://i.imgur.com/jSoZ2w5.png

Comment: Where is the link? Post the HTML code of link also

Comment: I think you totally misunderstood the concept of client and server side programming

Comment: To be honest this is very very basic stuff and there are tons of tutorials out there that covers this specifically. I suggest going back to some of the 101 tutorials (not trying to be mean)

Comment: Understood, its just something I have forgotten. What I am attempting to accomplish is very weird and I cannot find any articles relating to it. The difference between what I am doing and the 101 tutorials is trying to assign a php value inside a javascript and its not working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#select_box_id').change(function(){
          var newLink = $(this).val();
         $("#button_id").val("mailto:"+newLink);  //button selector 
    });
</script>
```

check this out.. http://jsfiddle.net/g6b5ywLh/2

Comment: I don't understand can you explain this?

Comment: you need to change button > value on change event of dropdown. 
get value of selected option and put it into button using javascript or jQuery

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand. I am a newbie when it comes to JS. I thought getelementbyid would be coming in to play here. But I'm not sure where to go with it.

Comment: ok. first you need to give some ID to <select> tag. In my case I assume this as <select id="select_box_id"> 
second you need to give ID to buttin which you want to alter on select of option which is <button id="button_id" >

then just apply this script

Comment: include jquery library as well

Comment: Maybe I am asking the wrong question? I wanted it to change the button to the email so if I have a list of Stores I can actively change different stores and it dynamically changes what email the button corresponds to.

Comment: @rut2 could you edit you answer to include your comments please

Answer (score 0):

See the following,

```
<div class="label">Select Store:</div>

<select name="stores" id="stores">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `storeconst` ORDER BY `Store` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo "<option value='".$d['GenManageEmail']."'>".$d['Store']."</option>";
}
?>
</select> 
<script>
$('#stores').change(function(){
      var selval = $(this).val();
     $("#sendto").val("mailto:"+selval);
});
</script>

<button name="send" value="" id="sendto" type="submit">Send</button>
```

You will need to include [jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) to make this working

**Edited:**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="storefrm">
<div class="label">Select Store:</div>
<select name="stores" id="stores">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `storeconst` ORDER BY `Store` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo "<option value='".$d['GenManageEmail']."'>".$d['Store']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<button name="send" onclick="submfrm()" type="button">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
function submfrm(){
  $('#storefrm').attr('action', 'mailto:'+$('#stores').val());
  $('#storefrm').submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have added in <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
and the send button doesn't do anything.

Comment: @hyperj123 you what to open the email client when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes using the "mailto:" so basically if i select Philadelphia from the drop down the button will reflect mailto:phillymanager@domain.com If I select New York from the drop down it will say mailto:newyorkmanager@domain.com

Comment: The dropdown is generated from a mySQL database and each column has a store location with and another column with their email.

Comment: This is not working either. I do appreciate your help though I have edited my post to reflect what I have in my index.php